# Buttonset Not Working With Radio

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I have some radio buttons ie

```
<div class="buttonset">
          <input name="radio12" type="radio" class="" id="radio5" />
          <label class="yesno">Yes</label>
          <input name="radio12" type="radio" class="" id="radio6" />
        <label class="yesno">No</label> 
</div>
```

I also have this code in the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".buttonset").buttonset();
                alert ("Buttons created");
            });
    </script>
```

And My radio buttons are not rendering as button as expected.

What am I missing?

This jsfiddle page has an example of it not working http://jsfiddle.net/jd3Km/1/

After @soderslatt's suggestion of adding resources I get this 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the jquery ui css

http://jsfiddle.net/jd3Km/5/

Comment: That Only changes the radio buttons to appear over the top of a div that looks like a big button. Not as expected here http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button Thanks for Trying

Comment: calling buttonset() and associate labels to its input will fix it, 
http://jsfiddle.net/jd3Km/18/